# Skia SkRegion::setPath failed

Tags: skia

I have a SkPath [**dispPath**] with verbs: 1st is moveto, others are lineto

```
{5118.000000 -16592.400391}
{5115.399902 -16591.400391}
{5112.200195 -16590.201172}
{5109.600098 -16588.201172}
{5108.399902 -16585.400391}
{5108.399902 -16581.400391}
{5109.200195 -16577.000000}
{5111.000000 -16571.800781}
{5113.399902 -16566.000000}
{5116.399902 -16559.400391}
{5120.200195 -16552.201172}
{5124.000000 -16544.000000}
{5128.000000 -16535.000000}
{5132.200195 -16525.599609}
{5136.399902 -16515.400391}
{5140.800293 -16504.599609}
{5145.399902 -16493.599609}
{5150.600098 -16482.599609}
{5155.800293 -16471.400391}
{5161.200195 -16460.201172}
{5166.200195 -16448.400391}
{5171.000000 -16436.800781}
{5176.200195 -16425.599609}
{5181.000000 -16416.201172}
```

and a SkRegion [**clipRegion**]

```
left=5108.399902, top=-16592.400391, width=72.600098, height=176.199219
```

When I call `bool succeed = myRegion.setPath(dispPath, clipRegion)`, it failed. myRegion is empty.

The **clipRegion** and **dispPath** should logically ***intersect***, but `setPath` failed.
Hope for someone's answer :)